# In angular 12 I have created a common header in which I have to pass username to header component which I am getting after login in login component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

In angular 12 I am creating a common sidebar component where in the userdata will be populated dynamically, using dataprovider service I am passing the data from login component to header component but I am getting userdata as null in header component as it is getting loaded in app component please help me out here.Below is my header.component.ts code and login.component.ts code

header.component.ts code

```
        ngOnInit(): void {
           let data= this.dataProvider.getLoginData();
           if(data){
             this.userId = data[0].USER_LOGIN;
           }
           else{
             this.userId = '';
           }
           console.log(data,this.userId,"user id")
          }
```

---

Login.component.ts

```
        validateUser(){
            const loginParam ={
              userId:"abc",
              password:"abc"
              serviceType:"UV",
            }
            this.apiService.validateUser(loginParam)
            .subscribe(
             (response:any) => {
                if(response && response.status== '200'){
                  console.log(response)
                  let res = response.result;
                  this.dataProvider.setLoginData(res);
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
                }
                else{
                  return false;
                }
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
```

Comment: Does the header component, always open AFTER the login component?

Comment: Yes, default route is login and here is my app.component.html code <app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>

Comment: Please share the code for `DataProvider` Service.

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  loginData: any;

  constructor() { }

  setLoginData(val){
    this.loginData = val;
  }
  getLoginData(){
    return this.loginData;
  }
}

Comment: I am not sure how your API validates the user, but might be possible that the first reply to the subscription is null, and that will be what it is stored in the loginData.